# Correct use of still

Tags: semi-modals

In the following sentence I think **still** is incorrectly used.

> He has a bad cold and sore throat. He may still get flu.

I think it should be **he may have got flu**

Comment: If he *has* the flu, he doesn't also have a cold. At least not normally. Then again, it's also unlikely to start off with a cold which then turns into the flu. That aside, the use of *still* is fine if you have something, and it could turn into something more or different. *So far, I've won $20 at poker. I may **still** win more before the night is over.* *Still* is used to talk about a future possibility in this context. On the other hand *may have got* is used to talk about a past or present possibility. So, the meaning is different. But both can be used.

Comment: A sore throat is one of the symptoms of a (bad) cold. Saying that one has a cold and a sore throat sounds somewhat odd whereas "a bad **cough** and a sore throat" (as the symptoms of both a cold and **the** flu) sounds okay.